# setting a source for all jquery in an application

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to Jquery but it turns out I used it quite a bit in my last application.  My problem now is that its reloaded every single time one of my pages is loaded/reloaded.  Is there an efficient way to reference it like we do a css or javascript file? for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/behavior.js"></script>
```

I would really like to be able to do this with the jquery...because its quite a mess when you look at the source code.  To avoid confusion: I already have jquery loaded.  For example...this is already in my html:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What Im trying to cache is all of the code I've built off Jquery.  For example:

```
$('#needDelete').slideDown('slow');
```

I have a bunch of these that need to be put into a file if that's even possible!  Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can put your code in a file and load it. The same as you do with jQuery.

Comment: I tried opening a file called custom.js.  I dumped all of the jQuery code into it and then referenced it.  Nothing worked.  Does there need to be something additional in the reference page itself?

Comment: No, but maybe you included it before jQuery? Or you load the code at the wrong time. We cannot really help you if we don't even know what you did. A like to a live pages would not be wrong.

Comment: @user791187 then you "referenced" it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course **you can save your JavaScript code in a separate file** (whether based on jQuery or not). Just keep your code separated and put it eg. in `main.js` file, then put a tag after jQuery script tag:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just for consistency and improved maintainability, it is easier if all the code is in one place than when it is often referenced within HTML like that:

```
<a href="#" title="" onclick="$('#popup').show();return false;" id="a1">show popup</a>
```

Instead of the above you could do this in a separate JS file:

```
$('#a1').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#popup').show();
}):
```

(of course the above code should be enclosed within `onload` or `ondomready` handler, so the code searches for elements after they become accessible - in case of jQuery and `ondomready` you can simply use: `jQuery(function(){/* your code executed when DOM is ready */});`)

Comment: What you call "consistency and improved maintainability" is really adding another layer of uncertainty and incompatibility on top of jQuery's botched selector-based "Unobtrusive JavaScript" approach.  Event-handler attributes have worked and are standards-compliant since more than a decade.

Comment: @PointedEars: I believe your comment is unconstructive and subjective - and is actually about jQuery itself. In my opinion if you have to write JavaScript that needs to be maintainable, and you have an application consisting of hunderds of views, then it is a lot easier to maintain this code using several JS files instead of writing inline JavaScript within views. And having to inspect hundreds of HTML partials in case of problems is a lot more tedious work than inspecting relatively clean JS files.

Comment: I think you are biased with regard to jQuery as well. You would sacrifice even more compatibility for perhaps easier maintenance?

Comment: @PointedEars: Since you edited your comment, I have to agree with the added phrase (that "_Event-handler attributes have worked and are standards-compliant since more than a decade._"). **Of course event attributes have worked and are used now. They are doing what they are supposed to do.** I was referring to **all inline JavaScript**, not only the one attached to event attributes. Generally if you are mixing a lot of HTML with complex JavaScript, you will have to deal it sooner or later, and I proposed the solution. Just separate application logic (eg. JS) from the presentation (HTML).

Comment: Lets keep comments constructive. If you want to have an extended discussion, please use chat.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is a JavaScript library. It consists of a single JavaScript file. All the documentation for it says to use `<script src="..."` to load it.

Update in response to edit:

The JavaScript you write that calls jQuery functions *is still JavaScript* and can be referenced from an external file just like any other JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

download jquery, and reference it like this:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
```

Or, for an even better option, you can use [google's cdn](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). This means that if a user comes to your site, and has already visited a site which uses the cdn, it will already have jquery cached.

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

and for the best option, to protect against the possibility of downtime of the cdn, combine the local copy and the cdn like this:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
if(!window.jQuery){
  script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src='js/jquery.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}
</script>
```

Comment: I believe your code should use `||` instead of `&&` or check only for `window.jQuery`, because jQuery can be simply used by referencing `jQuery` and `$` may not be accessible or overwritten (see [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

Answer (score 0):

I would refer jQuery from a CDN. This will allow the browser to do parallel download along with other resources from my domain, thus save some load time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The cdn version will be usually cached in your browser.

Comment: I edited the question: its not the jquery Im trying to reference...its the code built off of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this question. What do you want?

> I tried opening a file called custom.js. I dumped all of the jQuery
>   code into it and then referenced it. Nothing worked. Does there need
>   to be something additional in the reference page itself?

Why would you do that? You save some loading by decrease the number of different files, but the difference between one and two files is minimal.

Instead, do as `Frederik Creemers` suggested. Juse the jQuery-library at googleapis.com. The file is cached, meaning it will not load every single time a user visits your page. Only when the cache expires (not 100% sure how long this is). In addition, this library is used by many other sites, so you might be lucky and the user downloads it somewhere else and has it ready for use when going to your page.

Again, what you are asking (if I understood correctly) is pointless.